# Non-english characters in Zend_Form

Tags: zend-framework, encoding, character-encoding, zend-form

I'm creating a form using Zend_Form, and all he words that contains diacritics are not rendered. The encoding is set to UTF-8, the collation of the database is set to utf-8_unicode. What else should I do/check?

The page header:

`<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type">`

The Zend_form part:

```
        $user = Doctrine::getTable("aclUser")->find(1, Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
        $this->addElement('text','providerName',
            array(
                'label'     => 'Provider_name',
                'required'  => false,
                'readonly'  => true,
                'value'     => $user['name'],
                'filters'   => array('StringTrim'),
                'decorators'=> array(new Application_Form_Decorators_Custom())
            )
        );
```

Comment: Can your post some sample code?

Comment: Added. I don't know if it helps...

Comment: Is the database connection character set `utf-8` as well?

Comment: The collation_database variable is set to utf-8_unicode_ci

Comment: @Phil: Thanks for the suggestion. That was one of the problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. I added this settings in *my.cnf* and now everything is rendered ok:

```
[client] 
default-character-set=utf8 

[mysqld] 
init_connect='SET collation_connection = utf8_unicode_ci' 
init_connect='SET NAMES utf8' 
default-character-set=utf8 
character-set-server = utf8 
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci 

[mysql] 
default-character-set=utf8
```

Comment: FYI setting the character set via `SET NAMES` also sets the collation

Comment: I didn't knew that. Thank Phil!

Answer (score 1):

Could be an issue submitting the form itself

Does setting your form's `accept-charset` to UTF-8 help?

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8">
   [form elements]
</form>
```

Comment: Nice idea but I believe the problem was displaying initial form values, not accepting new ones